# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Todoo#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm learning rails through Mike Hibbert's videos, using windows 7, rails 4.0.2 and ruby 2.0.

At this one "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fr8u3l6RWOQ&list=UUFW_fvwCoF44MGWk74U_rFg" I am supposed to create a "Todo List", but I can't create a new Todo, I don't know why. **I get this error everytime:**

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Todoo#new
Showing c:/Users/Suporte 2/MikeHibbert/todo/app/views/todoo/new.html.erb where line #2 raised:

No route matches {:id=>#<Todoo id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, done: nil>} missing required keys: [:id]
Extracted source (around line #2):

1  <h1>Add new item to your todoo list</h1>
2  <% form_for @todo, :url => todoo_path(@todo) do |f|%>
3   <%= f.label :name %>: <%= f.text_field :name %>
4   <%= f.hidden_field :done, :value => false %>
5   <%= f.submit "Add to todoo list" %>

Rails.root: c:/Users/Suporte 2/MikeHibbert/todo

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/todoo/new.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_todoo_new_html_erb__1061113415_24422844'
```

This is my **routes.rb**:

```
Todo::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  root :to => "home#index"

  resources :todoo
end
```

My "create" functions in the **todoo_controller**:

```
  def new
    @todo = Todoo.new
  end

  def todo_params
    params.require(:todoo).permit(:name, :done, :id)
  end

  def create
    @todo = Todoo.new(todo_params)

    if @todo.save
      redirect_to todoo_index_path, :notice => "Your todo item was created!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

My **new.html.erb**:

```
<h1>Add new item to your todoo list</h1>
<% form_for @todo, :url => todoo_path(@todo) do |f|%>
    <%= f.label :name %>: <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :done, :value => false %>
    <%= f.submit "Add to todoo list" %>
<% end %>
```

And my **rake routes**:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action

        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#n
ew
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#c
reate
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#d
estroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#
create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#
new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#
edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#
update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#
update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrati
ons#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrati
ons#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrati
ons#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrati
ons#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrati
ons#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrati
ons#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrati
ons#destroy
                    root GET    /                              home#index
             todoo_index GET    /todoo(.:format)               todoo#index
                         POST   /todoo(.:format)               todoo#create
               new_todoo GET    /todoo/new(.:format)           todoo#new
              edit_todoo GET    /todoo/:id/edit(.:format)      todoo#edit
                   todoo GET    /todoo/:id(.:format)           todoo#show
                         PATCH  /todoo/:id(.:format)           todoo#update
                         PUT    /todoo/:id(.:format)           todoo#update
                         DELETE /todoo/:id(.:format)           todoo#destroy
```

Remembering I'm using the **devise** gem to manage the users.

Can anyone help with this issue ?

Comment: try removing `, :url => todoo_path(@todo)` from the form.

Comment: Tried already, the following error appears:

'code'NoMethodError in Todoo#new
Showing c:/Users/Suporte 2/MikeHibbert/todo/app/views/todoo/new.html.erb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `todoos_path' for #<#<Class:0x2fe6908>:0x4cf5048>

Comment: put this method   `def todo_params
    params.require(:todoo).permit(:name, :done, :id)
  end` in in the bottom of controller under `private`

Comment: It didn't work, the same error appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that you need to correct is your routes:

Replace

```
resources :todoo
```

With

```
resources :todoos ## Notice plural
```

You should be defining the RESTful route with pluralized resource name in lowercase.

Next, you need to fix the `form_for` in `todoos/new.html.erb`

Replace

```
<% form_for @todo, :url => todoo_path(@todo) do |f|%>
```

With

```
<%# Removed url option and added = so that form is rendered %>
<%= form_for @todo do |f|%>
```

`form_for` helper will take care of the routing based on the value of `@todo`. If `@todo` is a not an existing `todoo` record, the form would be submitted to `TodoosController#create` action
and if `@todo` is an existing `todoo` record then form would be submitted to `TodoosController#update` action.

Also, in order to execute as well as render the results of Ruby code in an `ERB template`, you need to use `<%= %>` instead of `<% %>`

**UPDATE:**

Rails follows the *Convention over confguration* principle. Make sure that you follow Rails naming convention while creating the MVC structure for `todoos` resource.

*Controller* name should be pluralized `TodoosController` within a file name `todoos_controller.rb`.

*Views* should be placed under `app/views/todoos` directory. Again notice that `todoos` is pluralized.

*Model* name should be singularized as `Todoo` within a file named `todoo.rb` and the corresponding *table name* in database should be pluralized as `todoos`.

Another thing that I would recommend is to update the routes references throughout the application in sync with the change `resources :todoos`.
For example: In the `create` action, :

Replace

```
redirect_to todoo_index_path, :notice => "Your todo item was created!"
```

With

```
redirect_to todoos_path, :notice => "Your todo item was created!"
```

Also, change the `todo_params` as below:

```
def todo_params
  params.require(:todoo).permit(:name, :done) ## Notice todoo and NOT todo
end
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the error:
`Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/todoo/new"

Rails.root: c:/Users/Suporte 2/MikeHibbert/todo`

Comment: Make sure that you first revert back all the changes that you have done in the code posted in question. Restart the server and verify again. If you still receive the error then let me know where exactly you are receiving the error: in controller or in view.

Comment: I'm pretty sure everything is the same as before. For the record, my controller is named as `todoo_controller.rb` not in plural, just like my view folder is only `todoo` could that be a problem ? 
I restarted the server and I'm still getting the same error. It's a routing error `"No route matches [GET] "/todoo/new"`.

Comment: Yes..that would be a problem. Let me update the answer to reflect it.

Comment: Read my updated answer with details about the Rails naming convention.

Comment: The creating page finally works! But now when I click "Add to todoo list" I get another error..

`ActionController::ParameterMissing in TodoosController#create
param not found: todo

Extracted source (around line #12):
10
11
12
13
14
15
          
  
  def todo_params
    params.require(:todo).permit(:name, :done)
  end
  
  def create`

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1>Add new items to your todo list</h1>

<%= form_for @todo, :url => todoo_index_path(@todo) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %><%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :done, :value => false %>
        <%= f.submit "Add to todo list" %>
<% end %>
```

I am currently doing the same tutorial, I had the exact same issue.  Some careful googling, and I came across, http://www.kylembrown.com/programming/learning-ruby-on-rails.  That is where I found the answer above.  Seems like it has to do with the route chosen.  Maybe someone else can enlighten us to the reason this corrected the issues.